# Using REST in MSVC 2008 C++

Tags: casablanca, windows-mobile-5.0

I am writing app for windows mobile 5.0 and I have to use REST to get the data from the server. Initially the idea was to use [Casablanca](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/) but it turns out that Casablanca does not really work with VS2008 (at least 2013 is needed, and, as far as I know, I can not build WM5.0 project on 2013), or maybe i do not know something o_O ? )

So the question is: how can I use REST in VS2008?

Comment: I edited your question quite a bit to make it clear what you are asking. However, it may be a bit too broad for SE, as it looks like you are asking for a tutorial on writing a REST client in C++. If this is not the case, you should clarify a bit. If this is what you are asking, I think the answer might be "write a REST client in C++", unless you are asking if there are some other frameworks that might be out there?

Comment: I am not asking for a tutorial , maybe other framework will be nice i have used casablanca few times so maybe i am too "attached" to it :/. The project i am working is huge and i have time only to end of this month so i traied to avoid writing REST client from scratch :/

Comment: Well ... the POCO lib looks nice at first glance but i am not sure if it will work with WM5.0 this the main problem if it would be typicall windows app i would not have any problem but it has to work on WM5.0 and ARM arch :/ ( it feels more and more like getting in too this project was a bad choice from my side :( )

Comment: Ok ... POCO supports CE so it should be ok i guess but still any ideas will be nice.

Comment: I have used POCO and it works amazing :).

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question :)